# IP Address Alias

Tags: router, ip, wide-area-network

I have a computer behind router with IP 192.168.0.166.
I would like to know if it possible to mask real WAN IP to it.

So in the end it would be visible as WAN IP but actually not.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do would be to use port forwarding in the router to provide only the desired services.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that and it is already done. Software will be listening on local IP which will be send to client. And I am sure clients will need WAN ip and not server local IP

Comment: If you're connected to the public Internet, you will have an external address that you can give them.  From the connection, go to www.whatismyip.com and it should report your "wan" IP back to you which you can provide to your clients (the exception being if you have multiple static IP addresses, in which case, you should already know what they are).

Comment: Software that I use has two parts, client&server. Then server has authorization and data servers. Authorization server ip is set in client config, but then data server ip is being sent from authorization server config which is my lolcal ip and it can not be set to wan ip otherwise software will crash