# Direct wan ip behind router

Tags: router, ip, wide-area-network

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IP Address Alias](https://serverfault.com/questions/151203/ip-address-alias)

I need to have a wan ip to be listen in ipconfig but computer is behind router.

Comment: So what is your question?  Care to tell us about what type of router?  How about giving us a hint about what type of WAN connectivity you have.

Comment: Currently if I type ipconfig I see only ip 192.168.0.133 which is given by router. I need that IP to be my actual WAN IP but stay behind router. In other words, have direct2internet alike connection/interface but stay behind router.

Comment: Your lack of general network knowledge leads me to believe that you're going about doing something trivial in a convoluted, needlessly-complex or unsecure way.  Like BillN said: you need to provide some more information as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Voting to close, too ambiguous.  DanSpd: In the context of most SOHO routers.. you probably want NATing or to specify a DMZ host.  Specifying the client as DMZ will be similar to plugging the modem directly to the PC.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details about your current configuration and what exactly you want to do we can only give general answers.
You may have two options if your router supports them:
1) Create a DMZ with a Public IP address and place your PC on the DMZ (assign it the public IP address)
2) Setup the router to forward some or all ports to the internal IP address.

Comment: Tell me more about solution #1 please

Comment: If your router supports a DMZ, and your have more than 1 Public IP address from your ISP, then you could assign the PC to a different Public IP from your WAN IP, and connect it to the DMZ,  how this works vary's from Router to router, some have a dedicated DMZ port (WAN,DMZ,LAN) some do it internally.   We really need more info from you.  
And I think for most uses,  #2 is what you want.